# XML to Csv convertion using SharePoint nintex

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, sharepoint-2010

I am trying out ways to extract List items from SharePoint list and convert them to CSV file using Nintex Workflow.

Trying similar solution as posted in [Click here](http://www.vadimtabakman.com/nintex-workflow-list-to-csv-uda.aspx) , i have managed to pull out data from SharePoint ,But i am facing some issue with the XML2CSV conversion node in nitex.
I have this piece of code ,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

<xsl:template match="/child::*">
<xsl:for-each select="child::*">
{WorkflowVariable:textXSLChunk}
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But when ever their is an "," in the remark field , it is considering it as next field. How can i make it skip the "," entry in the field value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enclose the Workflow Variable within {TextStart} and {TextEnd} brackets? This solution should work when the workflow converts your variable reference into the text the variable contains. For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

<xsl:template match="/child::*">
<xsl:for-each select="child::*">
{TextStart}{WorkflowVariable:textXSLChunk}{TextEnd}
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```